# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. not executing but compiling

Tags: java

I have simple program,

```
package access;

class Coffee {

    void met() {
        System.out.println("they accessed me");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }
}
```

I am in the path `E:\sarvari\access`. it's compiling properly, I have `.class` file in the access directory. My `CLASSPATH` has `".;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip;"` I couldnt figure out, why it's not executing.
    "java Coffee"
gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: access/Coffee
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: access.Coffee"
```

Answer (score 1):

first compile using

```
   javac -d .  FileName.java
```

then you should run the program using

```
 java -cp . access.Coffee // access is your package and coffee is your created class file.
                            // here . represents the present dir.
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use full class qualified name

```
java access.Coffee
```

Also if there is some problem that you are facing in classpath you can always do

```
java -cp . access.Coffee
```

(considenring class file is in current directory)

Comment: Further, the Coffee.class file must be in the access directory.

Comment: @Hot Licks: the OP says it is in his question: "it's compiling properly, I have .class file in the access directory"

Comment: And the *java* command must be run from the directory containing *access*, not from the *access* directory.